# Type conversion of a string read from stdin to int is giving me a 0

Tags: go, stdin

Code:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
fmt.Print("Enter a number")
input,_ := reader.ReadString('\n')
fmt.Printf("Type of the entered value is %T\n",input)
fmt.Println(input)
out,_ := strconv.Atoi(input)
fmt.Printf("Type now is: %T\n", out)
fmt.Printf("Value now is %d\n",out)
fmt.Println(out)
```

Complete beginner to Golang. I was trying to solve one of the problems from r/dailyprogrammer. I took the snippet to read the input from SO, as well as the strconv.Atoi function. The examples for this function make sense but when I apply it to the input I read from stdin, it gives me 0.

Comment: What exactly are you inputting? What does the error flag returned by `Atoi`, that you’re discarding, say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change your code a little you'll see that `strconv.Atoi(input)` is returning an error. I hope you've now learned an important lesson about how Go does error handling.

> Error is: strconv.Atoi: parsing "1\n": invalid syntax

```
out, err := strconv.Atoi(input)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error is: %v\n", err)
}
```

One way to fix this is by trimming `input` using [strings.TrimSuffix()](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSuffix):

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
fmt.Print("Enter a number")
input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
input = strings.TrimSuffix(input, "\n")
fmt.Printf("Type of the entered value is %T\n", input)
fmt.Println(input)
out, err := strconv.Atoi(input)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error is: %v\n", err)
}
fmt.Printf("Type now is: %T\n", out)
fmt.Printf("Value now is %d\n", out)
fmt.Println(out)
```

You can also use the [Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner), which doesn't require you to remove the `\n`:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
fmt.Print("Enter a number")
scanner.Scan()
input := scanner.Text()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Stupidly enough, I didnt at all consider the implication of putting a _ in the code. Also, is this the conventional way to take in input from stdin in Go i.e. using the NewReader function from the bufio package and then after reading the input, trim the\n?

Comment: I added an alternative which doesn't require to trim. :)